# maximum element in vector $x$ given $Ax=b$ (b contains random values)

Tags: linear-algebra

given
$$
Ax=b
$$

$A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is a **known symmetric** matrix, which is invertible and diagonalizable.

$x\in \mathbb R^n$ is a **unknown** vector (to be computed)

$b \in \mathbb R^n$ is a **unit** vector of **random** values.

As the $b$ is not fixed (with random values), one is not able to explicitly compute $x$. Then how to

1. evaluate the maximum of $|x_i|$ (the element with maximum absolute value) over all possible $b$?
2. evaluate the statistics of the maximum of $|x_i|$ given a random unit vector $b$? I imagine that $b$ lies on a unit sphere (in $n$-dimensional space), the operator $A$ transform the sphere into a unique blob shape (as $x$).

Comment: Do you mean the maximum of $|x_i|$ over all possible unit vectors $b$?

Comment: Is $A$ known to be invertible? If not, the answer is that the maximum is unbounded.